# Recursively find the kth largest int in list of list of int in Python

Tags: python, recursion

As a newbie in programming, I am trying to do a function to find the kth largest int in a list of list of ints. I tried list of ints before and it worked.

However, for this function, its base case has too many possibilities:

Ex: `[1, 2], [[], 1], [[1], 2], [[1], [1]]`

I got stuck at the base case. Can anyone give me a hint for this?

This function would operate like:

```
find_2smallest([1,1,3])->1
find_2smallest([[1,[]], 9, [[1], [3]], [4]])->3
```

Comment: Isyour homework assignment asking you to find the kth largest number in a binary search tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a generalized solution (you specify `k`) using extra arguments with default values to track both the smallest set of `k` found so far, and whether this was the top level of the recursion or a sub-level.  Sub-levels return the current smallest subset, the top level returns the last entry (which is the `k`<sup>th</sup> smallest value).  The smallest set of `k` is maintained using `heapq`'s `nsmallest` method.

```
import heapq

def find_kth_smallest(k, a_list, smallest_k = [], top_level = True):
    l = len(a_list)
    if l > 1:
        l /= 2
        smallest_k = find_kth_smallest(k, a_list[:l], smallest_k, False)
        smallest_k = find_kth_smallest(k, a_list[l:], smallest_k, False)
    elif l < 1:
        return []
    else:
        if isinstance(a_list[0], list):
            smallest_k = find_kth_smallest(k, a_list[0], smallest_k, False)
        else:
            smallest_k.append(a_list[0])
            smallest_k = heapq.nsmallest(k, smallest_k)
    if top_level:
        return smallest_k[-1]
    else:
        return smallest_k

print find_kth_smallest(3, [10, [9, 8, [[]]], [7, 6, [[5], 4, 3]], 2, 1]) # => 3
```

Answer (score 2):

some hints:

write a flatten function to convert list hierarchy to a single collection (with unique elements), sort and pick the k'th element.

sample implementation

```
def flatten(t):
     for e in t:
         if isinstance(e,list):
             yield from flatten(e)
         else:
             yield e



set(flatten([[1,[]], 9, [[1], [3]], [4]]))

{1, 3, 4, 9}
```

of course, this approach is not the most efficient (perhaps it's the least efficient).  You can return the first k elements from each sub level and  prune at k'th level at each merge.

Comment: what if i want to do the function with full recursion?

Comment: that will be more efficient!

Comment: is there another way for me to get rid of the bracket